# Why is setTimeout and setInterval's callback the first parameter?

Tags: javascript

This may turn out to be more of a history lesson than anything.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('turkey is done')
}, 500)

setTimeout(500, function () {
  console.log('turkey is done')
})
```

The second version arguably makes more sense and is more readable.

Comment: 'arguably' is the key word.

Comment: hind site is 20/20. I agree it does make sense to have the order flip flop. To keep the parameters on the same line as calling the function. There is no going back now. Even wrapping setTimeout/setInterval in a method that fixes it would be none standard so just live with it like the rest of us.

Comment: the function parameter is "required" - the timeout parameter is "optional" - the rest answers itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the second parameter is omitted, the timeout defaults to 0 seconds. Many developers often use timeouts to deal with some async issues that may arise.

You'll always have the callback, otherwise the timeout is useless, but you won't necessarily need the timeout to be more than 0 seconds. Params are ordered in precedence.

Comment: This is a good point. And probably inline with what he was thinking.

Comment: If you're going to make a timeout for 0 seconds, why not just use an IIFE?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple if you look at the [documentation for `.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

#### Syntax

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, [delay, param1, param2, ...]);
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, [delay]);
```

First parameter is required, all the others are optional. `delay` defaults to `0` the rest are optional and get passed on to the `func`.

Given how [function syntax is specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Defining_functions).

How would you put an optional parameter before a required one?